# Keeping Zend_Form from Rendering <form> tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a case where the UX/Designer laid out a form design that requires me to create the `<form></form>` tags on my own in the phtml template, rather than have Zend_Form automatically generate them due to some non input related markup I need to fill in.

How do you keep Zend_Form from rendering the form tags? I wrote the following override of the `render` function that could surely be improved upon, but I can't seem to do anything by manipulating the decorators.

```
public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
    {
        $content = parent::render($view);
        $content = str_replace('</form>','',$content);
        $idx = strpos($content,'>',4) + 1;
        $content = substr($content,$idx);
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're solving the wrong problem?  Perhaps it would be useful to explain why you have to manually create the <form> tags?

Comment: The display markup is more graphically complex than a simple spitting out of the form. There is a section of buttons that are wrapped a certain way, etc., etc. It comes down to either creating a bunch of custom decorators, creating a bunch of custom elements, or dropping the form tags and creating a bunch of the markup by hand (it's all static and not input elements except buttons).

Comment: If you're able to post an example of the completed HTML of a form, someone may be able to offer a solution.

Comment: The HTML of the form is irrelevant. I just needed to remove the wrapping `<form></form>` tags. What's inside of it doesn't change that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, the answer is quite simple:-

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('text');
$text->setLabel('text');
$form->addElement($text);
$form->removeDecorator('form'); // the bit you are looking for :)
Zend_Debug::dump($form->render());
```

Gives the following output:-

```
<dl class="zend_form">
    <dt id="text-label">
        <label for="text" class="optional">text</label>
    </dt>
    <dd id="text-element">
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="">
    </dd>
</dl>
```

ie no `<form>` tag rendered. I think that is what you need.

If you want to do this in every form automatically by extending `Zend_Form` then overiding the `render()` method as follows works:-

```
public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null) 
{
    $this->removeDecorator('form');
    $content = parent::render($view);
    return $content;
}
```

I imagine that's a more satisfactory solution for you than doing it seperately for each individual form.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Zend_Form_Decorator_Form within [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html).

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    'Form',
    array(array('tag' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => '')),
));
```

should work.

Comment: Your code ends up rendering like:

`<><form id="edit_user_form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/admin/edit-user" method="post"></form></>`

Comment: It removes all the input tags and **only** displays the `<form></form>` tags. I tried something similar w/ removeDecorator, addDecorator and got no love, so I decided to resort to string manipulation.